# How to create shortcut In Windows 7 64bit to a website forcing Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file, shortcut

I would like to create a batch file that will install a shortcut on the users desktop. The shortcut will go to a website using only Internet Explorer. I also want to add our icon to the shortcut. The end users will only have standard Windows Users rights on their computer.

Shortcut Target = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 
                   https://support.mysite.com
Shortcut Location = Desktop of user running the batch file, Location of icon = C:\Icons

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

In Vbscript you can force to open the site with Internet Explorer like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim WS,IE,URL
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
IE = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635952/how-to-create-shortcut-in-windows-7-64bit-to-a-website-forcing-internet-explorer"
WS.run DblQuote(IE) & " " & URL
'********************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*******************************************
```

Answer (score -1):

call this from command prompt or from batch file.

```
Echo [InternetShortcut] > site.url 
Echo URL=http://example.com/ >> site.url
```

for internet adresses you need `url` file.

Comment: This will use the default browser. The OP wants to force IE and override the default browser to open the URL.